# JTable getInstance not working

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am trying to load a `Table` of `JoomShopping` with category id 3 but what it is giving me only `EMPTY` when I do a `var_dump()`

From DB I can see there is a category with ID 3

```
    $category_id = JRequest::getInt('category_id');
    $category = &JTable::getInstance('category', 'jshop');
    $category = $category->load(array('category_id'=>3));

     var_dump($category);exit;
```

Please tell me where I am getting wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to save load reasult to any variable just use category object.

Try using this code -

```
$category_id = JRequest::getInt('category_id');
$category = &JTable::getInstance('category', 'jshop');
$category->load(5);
print_r($category);exit;
```

//For Joomla 3

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$category_id = $jinput->get('category_id', '', 'INT');    
$category = JTable::getInstance('category', 'jshop');
$category->load($category_id);
print_r($category);exit;
```